# How to call a css function on click of a button in angular?

Tags: angular

I need to call a css class and change the button's style once the click function is clicked.
How to achieve this?

```
<button type="button"  (click)="start(tId,uid)">START</button></p>
**CSS**
.Start{
  background: grey;
  pointer-events: none;
  color: #FFFFFF !important;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: 600;
  margin-right: 10px;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use ngClass https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass

You can bind your click to a variable e.g. `(click)="showClass = !showClass"` then add `[ngClass]="{'Start': showClass }"`